# python - Size limit of set data type

Tags: python

I have a list with 7,200,000 elements in it. When I try to convert it with set() it cuts out to 4,500,000 elements. What can I do to bypass this problem?

I'm using Python 3.2.2 x86 on Windows.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think your list has duplicate elements which are removed in set. Sets include unique elements only.

Comment: No, it has no duplicates. All elements was generated using PHP array with unique keys, e.g. $array['2FDD66593D'] = '2FDD66593D'

Comment: if you are 100% sure they are all unique, I don't know another reason/limit for the problem you are facing. But please check your keys generated by PHP. maybe there are some duplicate keys even if you think there shouldn't.

Comment: There is a size limit on any kind of data, but Python throws a MemoryError when you hit it. Duplicates are the only explanation.

Comment: Yes, it is. There was offset error in PHP script so there are duplicates. Million dollar mistake made by me.